# How to auto Increment Ivy revision number when publishing to Artifactory

Tags: ant, ivy, artifactory

Can someone please help me figure out how to increment revision number using IVY when publishing to artifactory.

After web search I found buildnumber can be used to do that but it does not work, am getting the below error.

```
<ivy:buildnumber organisation="${organisation}" module="${ant.project.name}" />

BUILD FAILED
C:\Workspace\ant\includes\ivy.xml:65:com.ultra_as.ib#ProjectName;1.1.3: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ivy file not found in cache for com.ultra_as.ib#ProjectName;1.1.3: please resolve dependencies before delivering (C:\Users\user1\.ivy2\cache\resolved-org-ProjectName-1.1.3.xml)
Total time
```

I am not sure what mistake am doing here.

Comment: You need to make a call to a resolve task before attempting to call the ivy buildnumber task. Examples of resolve tasks are "resolve" (obviously) and "retrieve". Why? It's the resolution stage where ivy reads the configuration files like ivy.xml and ivysettings.xml

Comment: Thank you very much Mark, But i really don't understand your comment, can you please reword it... thank you very much once again for your time... cheers...